# openssl_decrypt PHP to CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, php, openssl, cryptography, cryptojs

In PHP I use `openssl_decrypt($encryptData,'AES128',$key, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING|OPENSSL_RAW_DATA)` and I need the exact same thing with same option on JS so I use CryptoJS with this function `cryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptData, key, {padding: cryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding}).toString()`.
With PHP my decoded message start with `C7` with others hexa character. But in JS only decimal values.

Here `encryptData` and `key` on PHP and JS have the exact same value. But cryptoJS return something different from PHP.
I don't know what can be the problem. I've tried to change the base of my values with UTF8 or Base64. But nothing works.

How can I convert this function to crypto and have it working ?
Thank you !

PHP example :

```
$encryptData = hex2bin("D5F630E93F36C21293012D78E5A384F1");
$key = hex2bin("A254FE00A791AA74386E8DEF3712B256");

var_dump(bin2hex(openssl_decrypt($encryptData,'AES128', $key, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING|OPENSSL_RAW_DATA)));
//result : c704469332aa61804601008a92dc10e5
```

JS example : (and of course hex2bin return the same output than in PHP)

```
let encData = hex2bin("D5F630E93F36C21293012D78E5A384F1");
let key = hex2bin("A254FE00A791AA74386E8DEF3712B256");
let data = bin2hex(cryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encData, key, {padding: cryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding}).toString());
console.log(data);
//result : 326638346632336661323135353832343236376139343564
```

Result change every time I reload on JS.

Comment: How about giving a complete dataset (plaintext, key and ciphertext) and two minimal examples to reproduce the examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CryptoJS uses the `WordArray` type and provides [encoders](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders) for conversion, e.g. the `Hex` encoder.

In the PHP code, `aes128` is applied, which is an alias for `aes-128-cbc` and requires an IV. If none is specified, PHP implicitly uses a zero vector, which must be explicitly specified in the CryptoJS code. The CBC mode itself does not need to be explicitly specified, since it is the [default](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#block-modes-and-padding).

Moreover the PHP code disables padding, which must be explicitly specified in the CryptoJS code, since PKCS7 padding is the [default](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#block-modes-and-padding). Note that `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` does not enable Zero padding, but disables padding, i.e. the CryptoJS counterpart is `NoPadding`.

Your CryptoJS code must be changed as follows to be functionally equivalent to the PHP code:

```js
let encData = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("D5F630E93F36C21293012D78E5A384F1");
let key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("A254FE00A791AA74386E8DEF3712B256");
let iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("00000000000000000000000000000000");
let data = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    {ciphertext: encData}, 
    key, 
    {iv: iv, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding}
).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
console.log(data); // c704469332aa61804601008a92dc10e5
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Please also note that a static IV is insecure. Typically, a random IV is generated for each encryption, which is not secret and passed along with the ciphertext (usually concatenated) to the recipient, who separates both before decryption.

Comment: Awesome ! You saved my day. I was thinking that default mode on PHP was CBC and not ECB.

Comment: @Develogg - You're right `aes128` is an alias for `aes-128-cbc`. I was confused because of the missing IV. But PHP implicitly applies a zero vector. This gives the same result _for the first block_ as ECB mode, so decryption works here as well (as there is only one block). I have revised my answer accordingly.